# Create a recurring event at midnight using C#, Unity Game Engine

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

In a game, I want to trigger an event every night at midnight.  The following code is not working:

```
void Update()
{
    var tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString();
    var today = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

    if (tomorrow == today)
    {
        THE THING I WANT TO HAPPEN AT MIDNIGHT;
    }
}
```

In debugging I have found that THE THING I WANT TO HAPPEN works fine.  However, the event isn't triggering from the if statement.

I searched the archives for answers, and found some, but the solutions aren't working - this is almost certainly a simple error due to my extremely low-level programming knowledge.

Any assistance would be great...Thanks!

Comment: Think about it, tomorrow will always be 1 day later than today because you keep changing it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is effectively asking "`1 == 1 + 1`?" and the answer will always be no.

You need to keep the last execution date stored *outside* the method, and you also need to be more careful how you do your comparison. For instance, `DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now` might return false (and pretty often), because `DateTime` stores the time *down to the tick*, and if it's off by even one tick, it won't be considered equal.

Try this:

```
DateTime lastExecutionDate = DateTime.Utc;

void Update()
{
    var tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString();
    var now = DateTime.Utc;

    if (lastExecutionDate.Day < now.Day)
    {
        lastExecutionDate = now;

        // this code will be called as close to midnight as unity allows.
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it will be considered midnight immediately when the game starts. If it is, try using this for `lastExecutionDate` instead...

```
DateTime lastExecutionDate = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
```

Comment: Except this is probably one of those extremely rare cases where you don't want UTC. "Unity" implies a locally executing exe on a PC and presumably there's a reason why midnight is significant to the user.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've updated it to reflect that fact. Thanks for pointing it out. I do most of my time-related stuff on the server, and I learned a long time ago that if you use local time once, you're probably going to be using it forever. Even if it's incorrect. So I default to UTC, because you can always convert to local if you need to. But in this case, you're absolutely right. :)

Comment: Thanks for posting!  See my post above.  The gushier thank you to you gentlemen, as well.

Answer (score 0):

`if (tomorrow == today)` this will never be true. If it is *exactly* midnight (`Jan 01 2000 12:00:00.0000`) then this line: `tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)` will equal midnight...*tomorrow*, all the time (`Jan 02 2000 12:00:00.0000`).  The same applies to every other date-time.

You're better off checking to see if the current *time* is midnight, then store the current *date* somewhere and `DoTheThing()` only if it's currently midnight and the stored date *is not* today's date.

Of course, this also ignores the issue of "do you want the event to be triggered retroactively if the application is not actively run at midnight." In which case, `TimeSpan`s and `Last_run_date` may be of interest.

Comment: As I suspected, a dumb mistake.  Still, this site (and everyone who posted an answer) is amazing, and makes a big difference for me - it's the only place I'm learning anything about programming.  Much appreciated for a not-quite-novice.